# ORM SQLAlchemy: how to build a select/where query from a list/dict with hundreds of elements

Tags: orm, select, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I have two tables: "user" which is a list of users of the website and "post" which is a list of all the users' posts. 
Any user follows different users, like Twitter.
Any 'user' object holds a 'following' dict attribute containing a list of id.
Any 'post' object holds a 'user_id' label containing a id user.

I want to obtain a query that, from the table 'Post', collect all the posts with 'user_id'  matching the id's contained in the dict.

But such a query, translated straight,  would result in a SELECT  with  hundreds of  WHERE id= 1 AND id=2 etc in a row.  Is there a better way?

Comment: When you say that the 'user' object holds a 'following' dict attribute, can you please explain? Most databases don't support a column that stores a dict in any usable form, making this difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how your `following` dict attribute is persisted. If it were stored in a separate N-1 table `Follows`, assuming your db schema looks like:

```
User(UserID, ...)
Post(PostID, UserID, ...)
Follows(UserID, FollowsUserID, ...)
```

the SQL query to retrieve the data you want would be:

```
SELECT  u.UserID,
        p.*
FROM    User u
JOIN    Follows f
    ON  u.UserID = f.UserID
JOIN    Post p
    ON  f.FollowsUserID = p.UserID
```

Assuming the objects and relations are configured, the SA query to do the same job would like similar to:

```
u = ... # get desired User object
qry = (session.query(Post).
        join(User). # User will join to Post properly
        join(Follows, Follows.FollowsUserID == User.UserID). # specify the join condition
        filter(Follows.User == u)
      )
```